# Find substring with start and end position in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following data set.

```
id | event_type | ivmsmessage
-----------------------------

1  | gps_report | n/a,22,n/a,0,100

2  | gps_report | n/a,22,n/a,5,90
```

I want to extract no of records whose value in 'ivmsmessage' field in fourth place is zero. So the final output should be

```
id | event_type | ivmsmessage
-----------------------------
2  | gps_report | n/a,22,n/a,0,100
```

I tried locate() function to find the desired result but this also considers the remaining string.
This is locate() query I tried.

```
select id, even_type, ivmsmessage from live_events where locate(0, ivmsmessage,9) > 0;
```

Generates the following result.

```
id | event_type | ivmsmessage
-----------------------------

1  | gps_report | n/a,22,n/a,0,100

2  | gps_report | n/a,22,n/a,5,90
```

It considers the second record as well due to 0 in 90.

Is there any way where I can pass start and end position of the string so that the query only looks in that limited positions?

Any help would highly be appreciated.

Comment: should normalise this `invsmessage` field into a lookup table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`substring_index` is your friend here.

```
select * 
  from table1
  where substring_index(substring_index(ivmsmessage, ',', -2), ',', 1) = 0
```

[quick demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a7f0/4)

`substring_index(string, delim, count)` will give you everything to the left of `count` number of occurrences of `delim` in `string`.  If `count` is negative, it will give you everything to the right, with the count starting from the right. Combining the two allows us to zero in on a particular element in your delimited string.

In this example, `substring_index('n/a,22,n/a,0,100', ',', -2)` gives `0,100`, and `substring_index('0,100', ',', 1)` gives `0`, which we then test against.

Comment: Thanks @pala for the help but this query is not going to work in this case. 
substring_index() still returns both the records if used with negative number. There is also a possibility that I get 'zero' in the data before and after the desired location. So in before case, positive number will also not work because it will return records with zero character before the desired location.

Comment: @ZeshanKhattak  
What? This will extract the 4th value. Or the value after the third of four commas. So long as your data format doesn't change, this works. If it doesn't work for you, please provide accurate sample data rather than just two cases. Did you try the demo? The actual query combines two calls to substring_index

Comment: Thanks pala. It worked great. I overlooked the second 'substring_index' in your query. Apology for that.

Comment: @ZeshanKhattak ah great. I was slightly confused as to how it wasn't working - if you're happy with the approach could you please mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: Although this may work in this example, as a general solution it won't work correctly when the number of delimiters is less than what you're looking for, as it will always return something instead of empty string.  Try: select substring_index(substring_index('a,b',',',3),',',-1); My (down-voted by incompetence!!!) answer on the other hand, works in that case, too!  Try: select getpart('a,b',',',3);

Comment: I'll point you at the comments to this question where it already states this solution is applicable only if the input data doesn't change.  The question did not ask for a 'general purpose' solution, it asked for help with a specific problem.

Comment: For me, the data would not get changed. It will remain the same in terms of no of comma separated values.

Answer (score -2):

```
/*
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Function to return the Nth part from a delimited string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

drop function if exists GetPart;
delimiter //
create function GetPart(str varchar(1024),delim char,count int) returns varchar(1024)
begin
  if delim is null then
    set delim = char(9);
  end if;

  if count > 0 then
    return substring_index(substring_index(concat(str,delim),delim,count),delim,-1);
  else
    return substring_index(substring_index(concat(delim,str),delim,count),delim,1);
  end if;
end;
//
delimiter ;
```

You can use the above general utility function to get the N-th part of any string.  For your particular example it would be something like:

```
select id, event_type, ivmsmessage
  from live_events
  where GetPart(ivmsmessage,',',4) = 0;
```